# SharePoint 2013 workflownot availalbe for sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

tried to create SharePoint 2013 workflow for sharepoint online site but there was no option to select platform type as “Sharepoint 2013 Workflow” and getting the following message in SharePoint Designer 2013:

The option for the sharepoint 2013 workflow platform is not available because the workflow service is not configured on the server

Answer (score 0):

Their is one setting in the SharePoint admin center which block the Sharepoint 2013 workflows.

- Login on the SahrePoint Admin center with Tenant admin credentials. `https://urtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx`
- Make Sure **Connect Services** option is not Checked.[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes I have managed to fix the issues by going through these steps:

1. Go to: Site settings > Workflow settings    At the you see the title
   "workflow title (Workflow Health)"
2. Now click on Workflow Health (it's subtle indeed, but it's really a
   link)
3. On the next screen with the status per workflow, there will be
   a message that something is not activated, including an "Activate"
   button.
4. Click that "Activate" button, wait for 5 minutes (almost
   nothing is instantaneous on Office 365) and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

The service is working, at least for me... ;-)

[image]

You might not have the correct permissions. Are you a Site Owner or Site Collection administrator? One permission to check:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try to install SharePoint Designer 2013 Service Pack 1.

https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/other/recommended-sharepoint-designer-updates.html

Besides, here is a Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/62ad9e7f-20d3-4337-b4fe-1f6d0722ad05/office-365-sharepoint-designer-workflow-platform-not-available?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: He is talking about SharePoint online not SharePoint onPrem.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, i have changed my reply.